# How to add view below another view in UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiscrollview

In my app i am using `UIScrollview` to list details. In scrollview the first subview is `UItextview`, second `UILabel` and so on. But, when the textview content is more it overlaps the `UILabel`, searched a lot in SO and google but couldn't find the exact solution for my problem.

I am looking for

How to add `UITextView` below `UILabelView` or some other view?

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this,

```
[YOUR_SCROLL_VIEW addSubview:YOUR_TEXT_VIEW];
YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.frame.size.width, YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.frame.size.height);

[YOUR_SCROLL_VIEW addSubview:YOUR_LABEL];
YOUR_LABEL.frame = CGRectMake(0, YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.frame.size.height, YOUR_LABEL.frame.size.width, YOUR_LABEL.frame.size.height);

YOUR_SCROLL_VIEW.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, YOUR_TEXT_VIEW.frame.size.height+YOUR_LABEL.frame.size.height);
```

Change X or Y co-ordinate according to your requirement.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will try this and let you know

Comment: I tried your method but when i use  `_txtUse.frame = CGRectMake(0,  NameLabel.frame.size.height,_txtUse.frame.size.width ,_txtUse.frame.size.height == _txtUse.contentSize.height )` the text get hided..

Answer (score 0):

`UIView` has two methods to move a specified subview to the end/beginning of the array of views in his subviews property:

```
bringSubviewToFront: 
sendSubviewToBack:
```

You can try bringing your label to the front with:

```
[self.myScrollView bringSubviewToFront:self.myLabel];
```

Or send your textView to the back with:

```
[self.myScrollView sendSubviewToBack:self.myTextView];
```

*I used those methods in the past with `UIView`, `UIScrollView` inherit from `UIView` so it should work also, but I didn't have the chance to confirm that, It can be that the `UIScrollView` mechanism handle his subviews differently, so u need to check it yourself :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It doesn't seems to be working all views are in the same place as in the Storyboard